# Passing the parameters of a sklearn function as a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For convenience, I want to wrap sklearn functions within functions and pass to the wrappers the parameters of the sklearn function as a dictionary.  But I am not doing it right and I get an error.

My code:

```
params = {'alpha' : 1, 'kernel' : 'linear', 'gamma': 10}

def f_kernel_ridge(X_train, y_train, X_dev, y_dev, X_test, **params):


    from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge

    clf = KernelRidge(X_train, y_train, alpha , kerner , gamma)
    clf.fit(X, y)
    return clf

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-394-8240d87b78fc> in <module>
----> 1 Results = f_kernel_ridge(X_train, y_train, X_dev, y_dev, X_test, **params)

<ipython-input-392-331317c2e92c> in f_kernel_ridge(X_train, y_train, X_dev, y_dev, X_test, **params)
      8     from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
      9 
---> 10     clf = KernelRidge(X_train, y_train, alpha , kerner , gamma)
     11     clf.fit(X, y)
     12 

NameError: name 'alpha' is not defined
```

Comment: `clf = KernelRidge(X_train, y_train, **params)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
params = {'alpha' : 1, 'kernel' : 'linear', 'gamma': 10}

def f_kernel_ridge(X_train, y_train, X_dev, y_dev, X_test, params):


    from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge

    clf = KernelRidge(**params)
    clf.fit(X, y)
    return clf
```

1) don't "explode" params in the function arg

2) explode params in the call of `KernelRidge`

Comment: Modified. You're passing in `X_train` and `y_train` as args to `KernelRidge` at instantiation time, but that's not how that works. In your case, it thinks that `X_train` is `alpha`, so when you explore `params`, it thinks that it is getting 2 alphas